# How to count the number of values that has digits only in a list python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
data = ['ID:123 GE:m FN:Amir LN:Maleki MN:0400101010 EM:a@b.c ST:VIC',
' ID:b22 EM:b@d.c ST:VIC GE:F FN:Miniyi LN:Li MN:0430101210 MN:0432101215',
' ID:153 GE:m FN:John LN:Liu MN:040181010 ST:NSW EM:d@b.c']
```

I was wondering how to count how many IDs that contain digits only. Do I need to convert this list to a dictionary to do so or is there a simpler way?

thanks

Comment: How would you do this by hand?

Comment: Use a regex to find all matches and look at the results length. That should be more then enough of a hint to motivate you to try by yourself first before asking us silly questions.

Comment: You can always use regular expressions!

Comment: @Igle I started coding only couple of weeks ago and was not sure. Thank you for the hint but try not to be so rude.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex feels like overkill to me. Here is a `split` based solution:

```
>>> data = ['ID:123 GE:m FN:Amir LN:Maleki MN:0400101010 EM:a@b.c ST:VIC',
... ' ID:b22 EM:b@d.c ST:VIC GE:F FN:Miniyi LN:Li MN:0430101210 MN:0432101215',
... ' ID:153 GE:m FN:John LN:Liu MN:040181010 ST:NSW EM:d@b.c']
>>> 
>>> data_split = [[i.split(':') for i in s.split()] for s in data]
>>> IDs = [v for s in data_split for k, v in s if k=='ID']
>>> sum(map(str.isdigit, IDs))
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're trying to find the number of instances of something, your baseline is using a regular expression, or regex.

For your particular example, it seems like you can use the regex `id:\d\d\d`

`re.findall` will get you all matches
and `len(re.findall)` will get you the number of matches

I left out a comprehensive solution, so you can try yourself. Regexes are useful to pattern match in all languages. There may be a faster/easier way if you're familiar with certain libraries or methods, but regex will always be a surefire way to pattern match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions, e.g., the regex `\bID:\d+\b` will match the ID field followed by a digit-only value until the next word boundary `\b`. Just filter for those that match the regex.

```
>>> [d for d in data if re.search(r"\bID:\d+\b", d)]
['ID:123 GE:m FN:Amir LN:Maleki MN:0400101010 EM:a@b.c ST:VIC',
 ' ID:153 GE:m FN:John LN:Liu MN:040181010 ST:NSW EM:d@b.c']
```

Or if you just want to count, you can use `sum`:

```
>>> sum(1 for d in data if re.search(r"\bID:\d+\b", d))
2
```

Comment: Thank you. I haven't learnt regex yet but it will be useful to know how to use it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only check:

```
data = ['ID:123 GE:m FN:Amir LN:Maleki MN:0400101010 EM:a@b.c ST:VIC',
' ID:b22 EM:b@d.c ST:VIC GE:F FN:Miniyi LN:Li MN:0430101210 MN:0432101215',
' ID:153 GE:m FN:John LN:Liu MN:040181010 ST:NSW EM:d@b.c']

for i in data:
    print(i.split()[0].split(':')[1].isdigit())
```

output:

```
True
False
True
```

if you want those ID too then:

```
print([i for i in data if i.split()[0].split(':')[1].isdigit()])
```

output:

```
['ID:123 GE:m FN:Amir LN:Maleki MN:0400101010 EM:a@b.c ST:VIC', ' ID:153 GE:m FN:John LN:Liu MN:040181010 ST:NSW EM:d@b.c']
```